# Identify the date when data got inserted to an index in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have posted a data posted to my elastic search index, the data doesn't have any create date, Is there any way to check when the data got inserted in the index?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? :)

Answer (score 0):

Until 1.x there was a meta field called `_timestamp`, but in 2.x it became [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-timestamp-field.html). From 5.x is not even usable anymore.

You have to create normal date field and set its value explicitly each time you index a document.